# Join working differently

Tags: java, multithreading

Here, I was learning threads in java,and was stumbled upon join(). Now, **join(), should let the current thread exit its execution and then next thread should start**. However, I am getting a different output.
My code is

```
 public class join extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}

class bhago4 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException 
{

        join j1 = new join();
        join j2 = new join();
        join j3 = new join();
        j3.start();
        j1.start();
        try {
            j1.join();

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        j2.start();
    }
}
```

And the output I am getting is:

```
0
0
1
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
0
1
2
3
4
```

Now according to how much I have understood, when j3 starts it should print 0,then it is sleeping for 500ms,till then j1 starts, and it should continue until its ends, but that doesn't happen. o/p of both the threads are alternate. Why its happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand the output better, change code as follows

Add constructor in `join` class

```
 public join(String name){
    super(name);
 }
```

Change print statement as

```
System.out.println(i+" from "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
```

Change thread creation as follows:

```
join j1 = new join("j1");
join j2 = new join("j2");
join j3 = new join("j3");
```

output:

```
0 from j3
0 from j1
1 from j3
1 from j1
2 from j3
2 from j1
3 from j3
3 from j1
4 from j3
4 from j1
0 from j2
1 from j2
2 from j2
3 from j2
4 from j2
```

[join()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join()) allows thread to die.

Sequence:

1. **j3** started. slept for 500 ms and printed 0.
2. **j1** started in parallel. slept for 500 ms and printed 0. If you change sleep time from **500** ms to **50** ms, the output is un-predictable between **j1** and **j3**, which are running in parallel.
3. Both are running in parallel and printed 1,2,3,4 later with sleep time of 500 ms.
4. By calling join(), you are waiting for **j1** to die.
5. You have started **j2** after **j1** death. **j3** has been already completed by that time.

Comment: Thanks i understand it now, although my question was stupid one. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 1):

When you run `j3.start()` and `j1.start()` you are creating two CPU threads which theoretically run at the same time; therefore your output of `001122..44` is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

When join runnable starts it first waits 500 milis, then prints a number.

Both 1 and 3  start at the same time, but you are telling main threat to wait for j1 to end. In the meantime j3 is also printing. So you are reveiging duplicated numbers on the output.

When j1 is done, you exist `join()` lock, and j2 starts, but then it reaches end of program. Sometime it might not finish in time.

If you want o have a better understanding of what is happening, add to each thread a name, like:

```
public class Join extends Thread {
   private final String name;

    public Join(String name){ this.name=name; }
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            System.out.println(name+": "+i);
        }
    }
}
```

You can use [this](http://beginnersbook.com/2015/03/thread-join-method-in-java-with-example/) tutorial, it looks very similar to your example

Comment: But join() means, another thread(j3) will wait, until the thread on which join have been placed(j1) will end...thats the part m having trouble.